# "sslv3 alert bad record mac" error when using cURL over HTTPS

Tags: php, curl

I am getting the following error message when I try to HTTPS a website:

> Curl error: error:140943FC:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad record mac

It's getting weird because sometimes it works (can retrieve content), but most of time it doesn't. What does this message suggest? Thanks!

Comment: @0A0D: I don't think it's quite a duplicate, though it does seem related. The underlying issues may be the same.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes, the titles are different but the problem is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A related question(with accepted solution) is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496941/curl-php-request-executes-50-of-the-time) on SO

Comment: -1 Don't link to other answers like that. Flag as a duplicate instead.