# Python API call fails with [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_RECORD_MAC] sslv3 alert bad record mac (_ssl.c:1125)')))

Tags: python-3.x, rest, ssl, python-requests, macos-monterey

I recently "moved" to a new laptop (MacOS Monterey 12.2.1), and since then, my (very simple) API call does work anymore.
It worked fine before, and the VM where the same app is running also works fine.
I first thought I was backlisted, but I can still access the same API via Postman.

Minimum Example

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
requests.get("URL", auth=HTTPBasicAuth("XXX", "YYYU"))
```

Obviously, XXX and YYY is not the real authentication ;-)

The error I get is:

```
File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/requests/adapters.py:517, in HTTPAdapter.send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
513         raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
515     if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
516         # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
--> 517         raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    519     raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    521 except ClosedPoolError as e:

 SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.sportdata.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ju-jitsu/rest/event/categories/257 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_RECORD_MAC] sslv3 alert bad record mac (_ssl.c:1125)')))
```

I already tried with verify=False, but this did not help :-(

I must admit I am a bit lost :-(

Any suggestions and input are welcome.

Cheers,
Claudia

Comment: Is that 100% of the time? When looking for `SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_RECORD_MAC` I also found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4505050/469322

Comment: Hi yes, unfortunately, it is. I can reproduce the error with two systems running on Monterey and do not get it when running it on Linux. The theory now is that the libreSLL from Mac does not accept  sslv3 from the server (which seems to be an outdated mechanism)

Comment: SSLv3 is indeed obsolete, but 'sslv3 alert bad record mac' does NOT mean your connection is using it; LibreSSL keeps the texts from OpenSSL and the text for an alert states the _earliest_ protocol that _defined_ the alert, but in nearly all cases (including this one) the alert remains used in later protocols. That server supports SSL3 _and_ TLS1.0-2, _any_ Libre should do at least TLS1.0-2, and the handshake automatically uses the highest protocol supported by both sides. You could confirm with a net trace such as wireshark -- and get other parameters that might help narrow causes.

Comment: HI @dave_thompson_085 thanks for the hint. I have managed to install Wireshark but I would have no idea what to even look for. I see that there are various connections made but I can not even identify which is the one i am looking for. But thanks anyway :-)

Comment: Wireshark can filter by address (and port, among many other things); unless there are both working and failing connections to the same host (on port 443) at the same time (or nearly), it should be easy to isolate.